# Spring Hibernate Class mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-mapping

I am just working through mkyong tutorials . And upgrading a tutorial to use annotations of Spring3 and hibernate 3.6.9. Older version works but with my modification I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Customer is not mapped [from Customer]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [from Customer]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:664)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
    at com.mkyong.customer.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl.findAllCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy10.findAllCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at com.mkyong.customer.bo.impl.CustomerBoImpl.findAllCustomer(CustomerBoImpl.java:30)
    at com.mkyong.CustomerBean.getCustomerList(CustomerBean.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:470)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:553)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1293)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:446)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:77)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:824)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1661)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [from Customer]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3441)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3325)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:914)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
```

My code and mapping files are as below

**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="testa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Entity Class**

```
package com.mkyong.customer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public long customerId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    public String address;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    public Date createdDate;

// getters setters below 
}
```

**DAO**

```
package com.mkyong.customer.dao.impl;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.mkyong.customer.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer;

@Repository("customerDao")
@Transactional
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }


    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {

        customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(customer);

    }

    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer() {
                //This throws error
        return hibernateTemplate.find("from Customer");

    }
}
```

---

**application context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity / -->
    <import resource="classes/config/spring/beans/DataSource.xml" />
    <!-- <import resource="classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/> -->
    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.adit.spring.hibernate.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <!-- uncomment this for first time run -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testa"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:database="MYSQL" p:showSql="true" />
</beans>
```

**datasource.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

 <bean 
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
        <value>WEB-INF/classes/config/database/db.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Is your file really named persistance.xml? It must be persistence.xml.

Comment: it is named correctly . Sorry will edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you showed us the spring context.xml file. But what is strange is that you're using a persistence.xml file, i,dicating that you want to use JPA, but your DAO doesn't use JPA: it uses the native Hibernate API.

My guess is that the session factory is not configured correctly, because you assume it will automatically read the persistence.xml file, which won't be the case if you don't configure Hibernate as a JPA entity manager.

EDIT:

You declare a session factory in the XML, but it scans classes in the package `org.adit.spring.hibernate.entity`, which is not the package of your Customer entity. And you want to use JPA, so this session factory bean definition should not exist.

You want to use the JPA API, so you must inject an entity manager in your DAO instead of injecting a session factory. This injection is possible thanks to your definitionof the bean `entityManagerFactory`.

Change your DAO code to something like this:

```
@Repository("customerDao")
@Transactional
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        em.persist(customer);
    }

    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer() {
        TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c", Customer.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#orm-jpa for more information.

Comment: Added. I know I am lost . Yes I want to use jpa .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Hibernate as a JPA-implementation (as it looks like from your configuration), you should use [JpaTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html) and not HibernateTemplate. However, since Spring 3.1,JpaTemplate has been deprecated, and you should create your DAOs using EntityManager-reference:

> Deprecated. as of Spring 3.1, in favor of native EntityManager usage
>   (typically obtained through @PersistenceContext) Note that this class
>   did not get upgraded to JPA 2.0 and never will.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```